# How to implement a system wide text replacement in windows programmatically?

Tags: vb.net

I have a small VB .Net application that, among other things, attempts to substitute system wide typed text by the user(hotstrings concept). To achieve that, I have deployed 'ahk2exe' and 'AutoHotkeySC.bin' with my application and did the following:

When a user assignes a new 'hotstring':

1. Kill 'hotstring' exe script file if running
2. Append new hotstring to the script file (if non exist then create a new one)
3. Convert edited/new script file to exe (using ahk2exe)
4. Run the newly converted script exe
   (somewhere there I also check if the hotstring has been already assigned)

However, I am not totally satisfied with this method for the following two main reasons:

1. The extra resources deployed with the application.
2. Lag: The time it takes for the system to kill the process and then restart it takes a minimum of 5 seconds on my fast computer and more on other computers. That amount of time is much more than the time it takes the user to assign the hotstring, minimize/close the window and then test his/her new hotstring. When the user does so initially with no success they will think the process failed. So this method is not very good for user experience.

So, I am looking for a different method or implementation. May be using keyboard hooks? Or maybe adding a .dll library that achieves the same. Are there any resources you know about that might help (free or commercial)? What is the best way to achieve my desired goal?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementing what Autohotkey does would be a pretty non trivial task.

But I'm pretty sure that AHK supports an "autoreload" option for scripts

googling "autohotkey auto reload" turned up several pages discussing that very concept. IF that worked, all you'd have to do is update the script file and that's it, AHK should automatically reload the script.